# How can i figure out if & which hardware may be causing a write to a file to take longer than it should?

Tags: windows-7, event-viewer

I saw this message in Event Viewer a couple of times, and I'm not really sure what it means. How can I figure out what is causing this issue and what can I do to resolve it?

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ESENT
Event ID:      508
Task Category: Performance
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic

wuaueng.dll (1584) SUS20ClientDataStore: A request to write to the file 
"C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\Logs\edb.log" 
at offset 1231360 (0x000000000012ca00) for 512 (0x00000200) bytes succeeded, 
but took an abnormally long time (71 seconds) to be serviced by the OS. 
This problem is likely due to faulty hardware.
```

Comment: The only device it could be is your storage device.

Comment: Not quite, as the connector and by association the motherboard might have something to do with it. But unless this occurs frequently, I wouldn't bother. Mainly because multiple processes can access the same disk, thereby reducing bandwidth.